# I screwed up! Sound didn't work tried to fix... lost a large amount of my system settings

Tags: 14.04, sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, system-settings

I was following this guide, attempting to make my bluetooth headphones work: http://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/ and then my [system settings (mostly) disappeared!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYNDl.png)

I followed the 1st alternative:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio
sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio
sudo alsa force-reload
```

I restarted, and there was no sound icon in the top bar... turns out I lost a lot of my system settings.

If you need any more info about the computer, please give me the terminal commands to get that information to you. I'm still trying to learn.

Comment: When pulse audio was first released (long ago) it was buggy and so some people decided to hate it rather then learn to configure it or file bug reports. Pulse audio is now mature and as you can see the advice to remove it is very bad advice on any distro. I suggest when you have problems read the official documentation or ask for help. IMHO it is also poor advice to remove and reinstall packages. See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingSoundProblems and post relevant system information once you restore your system.

Comment: Yes, I'm going to be much more careful about what advice I follow now. I've got my system settings back but, I'm not sure what system information you're asking for. The page you gave is about reporting bugs. My audio is on. Is this page better? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure Again I see it asking me to do something with pulse audio though.

Comment: @Kelsey - Since the answer worked, please mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: I'm sorry I was still waiting on trying to figure out my sound issues (I still have none) should I open another question? Also I'm new, do I click "Answer Your Question" Sorry, again, for my stupidity lol *edit* I just noticed you edited out my sound issue and I hit the check button. Thanks!*

Comment: Look at the link I gave you and open a new question with the relevant information. We can not help you if you simply state "sound is not working"

Comment: I have read the link, but I'm still not sure what the relevant information you need is. Should I just submit a bug report?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I've found a Linux friendly repair shop to bring it to (after a few phone calls). It's just over my head. But, I really want to thank you for your help and advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic system software packages like `ubuntu-desktop`, `unity-control-center` and `unity-control-center-signon` depend on the `pulseaudio` package. If you uninstall `pulseaudio`, those packages will be removed too, leaving your system pretty empty. To fix this, you could reinstall those packages using the package manager:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop unity-control-center unity-control-center-signon
```

Comment: This brought back my system settings!! Thank you!